# generalisation of matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(XA) = \mathrm{rank}(X)$.  I would like to prove that then there exists a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times p}$ such that $XAB = X$.

If $A$ is square and invertible, clearly one can take $B = A^{-1}$.  If $A$ has linearly independent rows, one can take $B$ to be the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$.  Does $B$ exist for general $A$?  If the statement is wrong in general, does it hold for $q = \mathrm{rank}(X)$?

Comment: If $X\ne0$, I think $A$ has to be an invertible square matrix for the statement $\operatorname{rank}(XA)=\operatorname{rank}(X)$ to hold. Also, $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leqslant\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\leqslant\min\{p,q\}$.

Comment: @Cheesecake I don't think that $A$ needs to be square.  If I append zero columns to $X$, I can append arbitrary rows to $A$ (values don't matter, because they are multiplied by the new zeros) and things still work: I can extend $B$ by zero rows to get back the new zero columns in $X$.  Maybe the general case is just rotated versions of this example?

Comment: note iif $A$ has full row rank, it is a surjective map and has a right inverse over any field -- this has little to do with Moore-Penrose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works over any field. As $\operatorname{range}(XA)\subseteq\operatorname{range}(X)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(XA)=\operatorname{rank}(X)$,
we have $V:=\operatorname{range}(XA)=\operatorname{range}(X)$. Let $Y$ be any matrix whose columns form a basis of $V$. Then $X=YP$ and $XA=YQ$ for some matrices $P$ and $Q$. Since $YQ\,(=XA)$ has the same rank as $Y$ and $Y$ has full column rank, $Q$ must have full row rank. Therefore $Q$ has a right inverse $R$. Let $B=RP$. Then $XAB=YQRP=YP=X$.

This means $XAB=X$ is a consistent system of equations. So, if the underlying field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, $B=(XA)^+X$ is a solution to $XAB=X$.

Comment: May I ask if $\operatorname{rank}(Y)=\dim V=\operatorname{rank}(AX)=\operatorname{rank}(YQ)\implies\operatorname{rank}(Y)=\operatorname{rank}(YQ)$? Is that the correct deduction?

Comment: @Fractal If we ignore your typo (it should be rank(XA) rather than rank(AX)), yes.